# how to drill a 2 1/2 in by 5 in long hole in wood?

Tags: tools, woodworking, drill

I am wanting to make my own tiki torches, by drilling a hole 2 1/2 in wide by 5 inches deep in the end of a small log.  I can't seem to find spade bits any bigger then 1 1/2 in, and nothing long enough to drill 5 inches deep.  Can any one tell me if this is possible?  Surely in this day and age it is!

Comment: At that depth, my preference would be to use an auger bit but similar to spade bits they cap out round 1-1/2".  Forstner bit  (as the other two mentioned) is your best bit at 2-1/2".  Make sure you have a drill up for the task with second handle to provide better control.

Answer (score 8):

You want a [Forstner bit](http://www.traditionalwoodworker.com/Forstner-Bits/departments/270/) and an extension shaft.

[image]

Comment: Beat me by one minute while I was getting the Amazon link! :) Good point about the extension shaft.

Comment: At the price that will cost, you might as well just buy the torches.

Answer (score 6):

The tool you need is a [2 1/2" Forstner bit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ENU87C). There's going to be a lot of torque resistance, so you may need to use a drill press instead of just a handheld drill.

Comment: 2 1/2 is manageable by hand and especially since this is not finish quality work.  Just run the bit slowly (~400 rpms) so you don't burn the wood and dull the bit.

Answer (score 0):

Other methods:

- Drill with the spade bit then put the log in a lathe and enlarge the
  hole out with a boring tool.
- As above but put the boring bit in the lathe and bring the log to the
  tool. You'd do this if the log is too big for the lathe.
- Drill lots of small holes covering the area of the intended hole,
  then chisel out the remaining wood.